# Why is Google lighthouse complaining about image size and weight with picture tag?

Tags: html, lighthouse

I used picture tag inside a carousel with media query and webp images. But when I test it in Chrome I get 2 notices on images: "Properly size images" and "Serve images in next-gen formats"

```
<div class="splide-slide-contaniner"><picture class="carousel-item-picture bg-cover">
<source media="(max-width: 575px)" srcset="../static/images/banner-home/mobile/img-banner-1.webp" draggable="false" type="image/webp" alt="banner slide 1">
<source media="(min-width: 576px)" srcset="../static/images/banner-home/desktop/img-banner-1.webp" draggable="false" type="image/webp" alt="banner slide 1">
<source media="(max-width: 575px)" srcset="../static/images/banner-home/mobile/img-banner-1.jpg" draggable="false" type="image/jpeg" alt="banner slide 1">
<source media="(min-width: 576px)" srcset="../static/images/banner-home/desktop/img-banner-1.jpg" draggable="false" type="image/jpeg" alt="banner slide 1">
<img src="../static/images/banner-home/desktop/img-banner-1.jpg" draggable="false" alt="banner slide 1">
</picture>
</div>
```

It seems like it is only seeing the IMG fallback tag.

Comment: do you want to share a link to your site in the comments, there are a lot of unknowns that may be causing this, the HTML looks OK at a first glance, however the correctly sized images part could be because your images are too large still etc.

Comment: I'm not allowed to share the url but lighthouse mobile report in chrome refers to <img src="../static/images/banner-home/desktop/img-banner-1.jpg" draggable="false" alt="banner slide 1"> so it seems like it is ignoring <source> tags and fallback to <img>